# How to search and replace GET parameters with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I try write a rewrite rule on an apache webserver configuration in the httpd.conf file, which should replace every GET parameter key which contains &foo= to &poo= but shouldn't change any other GET parameter.
For example:

```
https://test.com/imb/rs/search?test=abc&foo=123&test2=def&foo=456
```

Should be changed to:

```
https://test.com/imb/rs/search?test=abc&poo=123&test2=def&poo=456
```

I tried it with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&foo=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1?&poo=%2 [NC]
```

But it only changed the last occurrence of foo to poo.

My httpd.conf file is structured as follows:

```
<Directory ~ "^/imb/rs/*">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&foo=(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1&poo=%2 [NC]
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&foo=(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1&poo=%2 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

The /imb/rs/ part is written because the url starts with https://test.com/imb/rs/ and continues after that. I thought that would match my case.

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this?

Comment: What if this URL parameter exists at the start of the query string (in which case there is no `&` prefix)? Or is that not possible in this scenario?

Comment: No it is not possible in this scenario. It always starts with a & prefix

Comment: The directive you've posted is an internal rewrite (not a redirect) so it doesn't actually replace anything in the public URL - is that the intention?

Comment: Yes exactly. It isn't a redirect to another website. I just want to achieve to replace every occurrence of foo to poo.

Comment: In that case, the code you posted in the question should already do as you require, except that you have an erroneous second `?` in the _substititution_ string (which will mess up the other values). ie. `$1?%1?&poo=%2` should be `$1?%1&poo=%2`. Maybe you have a conflict with other directives? How are you testing this?

Comment: Where exactly are you using these directives? In `.htaccess` or somewhere in the server config? (As written, this would only work as intended (and replace all params) if used in `.htaccess` - or a _directory_ context).

Comment: I write them in the httpd.conf file in the <Directory> container.
You were right, the second ? character was wrong, but even without it, it still only replaces the last foo to poo.

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of this `<Directory>` block. As I say, the rule you've posted would already work (by itself) to rewrite the example URL you've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <Directory ~ "^/imb/rs/*">
>    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>    AllowOverride All
>    Order allow,deny
>    Allow from all
>    RewriteEngine on
>    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&foo=(.*)$
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1&poo=%2 [NC]
> </Directory>
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>    RewriteEngine on
>    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&foo=(.*)$
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1&poo=%2 [NC]
> </IfModule>
> ```

There are a few issues here. The `<Directory>` container is not going to match the request, so the mod_rewrite directives inside this container are not processed. Only the mod_rewrite directives outside the `<Directory>` container are processed, but this will only replace the *last* instance of `&foo=` in the query string (since the regex is *greedy* and the rewrite engine makes just a single pass in a vHost/server context).

> ```
> <Directory ~ "^/imb/rs/*">
> ```

You are mixing regex and wildcard syntax. However, this should be an absolute filesystem path, not a URL-path, as this appears to be ("url starts with `https://test.com/imb/rs/`"). But you do not need to use the regex version of the `<Directory>` directive here anyway. I'm assuming `/imb/rs` is a physical directory and not simply a virtual URL-path?

> ```
> AllowOverride All
> ```

You are explicitly enabling `.htaccess` overrides. If you do have a `.htaccess` file that contains mod_rewrite directives in this directory then this will completely override the `<Directory>` container in the server config. You should probably be disabling `.htaccess` overrides altogether.

> ```
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
> ```

These are Apache 2.2 directives and are formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4 (which I would assume you are using). You should be using the equivalent `Require all granted` instead. (But you do need to make sure you are using Apache 2.4 directives throughout - do not mix the two.)

> ```
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> ```

*Aside:* Are you intentionally allowing mod_autoindex to generate directory listings of your content? Generally, this should be disabled (ie. remove `Indexes` from this rule).

Try the following instead:

```
<Directory "/absolute/file/path/to/imb/rs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)&foo=(.*)
   RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1&poo=%2 [L]
</Directory>
```

And remove the rule from outside the `<Directory>` container.

So, the rule you had in the beginning was basically OK. The start-of-string and end-of-string anchors are not required here, since the regex is *greedy*. The `NC` flag is not required. The `L` flag is not strictly required, but would be if you add any more rules later.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution which works only with 1 occurrence, not with multiple.

This one takes only the first occurrence:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)foo(.*) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1poo%2 [NC]
```

This one takes only the last occurrence:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)foo(.*) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1poo%2 [NC]
```

But I couldn't find a way to replace all of them.

Comment: You should add any additional information to your question, rather than writing a non-answer. However, these are really no different than the example you've posted in the question, except these rewrite to a URL-path, as opposed to a file-path (unless you also have a `RewriteBase` directive defined - which is not stated in the question).